# Запрос установленных приложений через скрипт

Tags: powershell

Добрый вечер!

Мне необходимо получить список установленных приложений на компьютере через скрипт только с выбранными столбцами. Такой скрипт вызывает ошибку

```
$installApps = wmic product get Name, Version, InstallDate, InstallLocation /format:csv
```

Ошибка

```
WMIC.exe : Invalid GET Expression.
+ wmic <<<<  product get Name, Version, InstallDate, InstallLocation /format:csv | Out-File "D:\Volgablob\Debug\test.txt"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invalid GET Expression.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Пытался выполнить так:

```
wmic
$installApps product get Name, Version, InstallDate, InstallLocation /format:csv
exit
```

Файл со скриптом в таком случае выполняется бесконечно

Как можно написать файл со скриптом так, чтобы он получал только выбранные колонки и не зависал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых убираем пробелы

```
wmic product get name,version,InstallDate,InstallLocation
```

А во-вторых указываем куда выводить данный файл.

```
wmic /output:C:\Users\InstallList.csv product get name,version,InstallDate,InstallLocation /format:csv
```

Соответственно, если нужна переменная, то

```
$installApps = wmic /output:C:\Users\InstallList.csv product get name,version,InstallDate,InstallLocation /format:csv
```

Answer (score 0):

## Вывести список установленных программ для x86 системы

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
ForEach-object {(Get-ItemProperty Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::$_).DisplayName}
```

## Вывести список установленных программ для x64 системы

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
ForEach-object {(Get-ItemProperty Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::$_).DisplayName}
```